# Are there any documented cases of attackers using 'Free Trials' as an attack vector?

Tags: attack-vector, theory

We live in an age where a lot of services are hosted in various cloud-based infrastructures. And a lot of these infrastructures are based around a "pay as you go model". I.e. The more servers you spin up, the more database IO you use, the more incoming/outgoing data there is, etc, the more you pay.

We also regularly expect such services to offer some kind free trial/"try before you buy" scheme in order to evaluate whether we want to purchase them outright.

I was wondering if there had ever been any documented cases of malicious agents using "Free Trials" as an attack vector. For example, if a service had a free trial scheme that was only limited by unique email addresses, couldn't an attacker with a sufficiently large quantity of email addresses simply start up hundreds of thousands of trials, and as a result, incur large costs to the business in question?

I know many free trial schemes still require a valid credit card on file as a means of mitigating this issue (and others), but I figure it must have happened somewhere before and would be keen to find out more if such an event and how they responded.

EDIT: In this case I'm referring to an attack on the business, not the hosting infrastructure. The idea being to cause enough extra resource usage (whether that's load/persistent data/etc) as to cause a significant financial cost to the business.

Yes I'm making an assumption that for the scenario I'm outlining, the free trial is somehow causing extra resources to be consumed for the purposes of this attack. If I didn't make that (plausible) assumption, then there wouldn't be an attack vector, and then there wouldn't be question. And naturally I'm assuming that the business wasn't savvy enough to think about this before it became a problem.

This is essentially a theoretical/academic question, with the hope that there is a tangible example of this kind of attack being used in reality. If there isn't then fair enough.

Comment: It appears to me that you're assuming the service provider would be spinning up servers simply in response to user registration (say, one new server per 100K registered users), rather than in response to actual load. To put actual load on the service, the attacker would still need somewhere from which to originate that traffic.

Comment: An attack on whom? The cloud-based infrastructure? And assuming that the validity checks do not also include IPs or other factors? One would need a lot of email addresses, and a lot of IPs to launch quite a number of free trials for the sole purpose of *maybe* causing resource exhaustion on the infrastructure.

Comment: One could argue that AOL was a virus.  I also remember having to reformat my computer after trying some of those "Freeware" CDs that use to come with gaming magazines.

Comment: In the end, I don't think this question, or the hypothesis, is well-formed. You are assuming that somewhere, at some time, a provider did not check enough things to prevent high volumes of registrations and that the provisioning for all these free registrations cost the provider enough for the "attack" to have an impact. How far back in history are you interested? 2000? 2001? I could tell you stories. Why do you want to know any of this? Is it not enough to perform a cost/benefit analysis of the registration process to the provider?

Comment: A couple years ago, I heard of a group using AWS free accounts in a small scale DOS attack.  Might be a good starting point for people who want to do the research to answer this...

Comment: @aCVn Yes, you're correct I'm making that assumption. I know that generally resources are set to spin up to respond to actual load, but conceivably someone could  set things up to respond to predicted load. E.g. "We have X users registered so to be able to handle Y% of them being active simultaneously we need at least Z servers up at all times"

Comment: @schroeder You're generally right about the assumptions I'm making for this scenario. But that's the point. I'm not suggesting it's a common place issue or that there aren't ways to mitigate it. I'm asking if, under the conditions where a business failed to anticipate/mitigate this problem, what happened as a result? This is for personal interest, as I failed to find any documented cases of this in my searching so far. And if you have stories about it happening please let me know. I assumed this would be a more recent problem but if you have older examples they would be of equal interest.